# How to disable Chart Tooltips on Ext JS?

Tags: javascript, extjs

Ext JS 3.4.0: How to disable Chart Tooltips?

My code start like this:

```
// more complex with a custom look
chart = new Ext.Panel({
    //iconCls:'chart',
    border: false,
    frame: false,
    width:'100%',
    height: 400,
    //autoHeight:true,
    layout:'fit',
```